# BeautifulSoup not finding meta tag information

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

All three titles return 'None'. However, when I view the page source, I can clearly see `twitter:title`, `og:title` and `og:description` clearly exists.

```
url = 'https://www.vox.com/culture/2018/8/3/17644464/christopher-robin-review-pooh-bear-winnie'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

title = soup.find("meta",  property="twitter:title")
title2 = soup.find("meta",  property="og:title")
title3 = soup.find("meta",  property="og:description")

print("TITLE: "+str(title))
print("TITLE2: "+str(title2))
print("TITLE3: "+str(title3))
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find("meta",  property="twitter:title")` must be `soup.find("meta",  {"name": "twitter:title"})` (it's a name, not a property). The other two lines work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `User-Agent` in headers, also `twitter:title` is in `name` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.vox.com/culture/2018/8/3/17644464/christopher-robin-review-pooh-bear-winnie'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

title1 = soup.select_one('meta[name=twitter:title]')['content']
title2 = soup.select_one('meta[property=og:title]')['content']
title3 = soup.select_one('meta[property=og:description]')['content']

print("TITLE1: "+str(title1))
print("TITLE2: "+str(title2))
print("TITLE3: "+str(title3))
```

Prints:

```
TITLE1: Christopher Robin is a corporate cash-in, but it fakes sincerity better than most
TITLE2: Christopher Robin is a corporate cash-in, but it fakes sincerity better than most
TITLE3: Winnie the Pooh and pals return to give their old friend a pep talk in a movie overshadowed by the company that made it.
```